# Hi im new to django, i been trying to implement signin/signup application

Tags: python, django

I been trying to implement a sign-in/signup application. If I had to filter the specific object from the database what parameters I should use for the filter() method? now I have used all() which gives all the objects what if I want the details of the only person who has the account and trying to sign-in and if not tell him to signup.

views py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from webspaces.models import merchant
from webspaces.serializers import merchantSerializer
# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def signin(request):
    try:
        ex=merchant.objects.all()
    except merchant.DoesNotExist:
        return Response("status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND sign-up first")

    if request.method=="GET":
        serializer=merchantSerializer(ex, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def signup(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        serializer=merchantSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.erros, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models py

```
class merchant(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __self__(self):
        return self.email
```